# How to map through nested array of objects in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to map through an array, and for each key, map through the nested array of objects to print out grouped values.

I keep getting .map() is not a function for my nested arrays.

I have tried Object.Keys for the objects and map() for the arrays but I can't seem to get anything to print correctly.

Grouped Array

```
{Airport: Array(1), Motorway: Array(2), Other: Array(2), Train: Array(2), Subway: Array(1)}
```

Nested Arrays

```
 Airport: Array(1)
  0: {Station: "Airport", Description: "This is a description for the Airport", …}

 Motorway: (2) [{…}, {…}]
```

Trying to print the mapped results:

```
 return (
    <Wrapper>
        {Object.keys(list).map((key) => {
            key.map((station) => {
                console.log(station);
            })
        })}
    </Wrapper>
)
```

I thought as the parent was an object, and the children are arrays, that Object Keys then the map function would work, but it throws the .map() is not a function error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: the second map should be on `list[key]` instead of just `key` (which is a string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why this doesn't work is because you are trying to do `.map` in the `key`. `key` is just an string.

You should do the mapping over `list[key]` wich is the array

```
    {Object.keys(list).map((key) => {
        return list[key].map((station) => {
            console.log(station);
            // you should return something here
        })
    })}
```

Another thing you can do is loop through the values.

```
    {Object.values(list).map((value) => {
        return value.map((station) => {
            console.log(station);
            // you should return something here
        })
    })}
```

This way, `values` is the array you want and you can use `.map`.

Answer (score 1):

the great option from me, you define that object not on jsx, like this

```
const objMap = Object.keys(list).map((key) => {
    return list[key].map((station) => {
        station : station[key].station
        description : station[key].description
    })
});
```

and then on jsx you can call

```
{objMap.map(e => console.log(e.get("station"))}
```

Comment: I might even like this answer more since you could extract the messy code from your jsx. Nice one

Comment: ty [Y. Gherbi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6822962/y-gherbi)